# How to burn 6.6GB of DVD content on a standard 4.3GB DVD in macOS?

Tags: macos, software-rec, dvd, burning, authoring

There is a question I see popping on and on at forums but with no "good" answer.
I've copied a DVD to my hard drive and it is about 6.6 GB.
Is there any software that will help me to burn it into a 4.3 GB disk?

Comment: Do you know anybody that's managed to do that? If you copied the DVD on the hard drive and it's 6.6 GB, I'm not sure you can fit it on a single layer DVD.

Comment: @alex: the size can be reduced by removing special features and extra audio tracks (e.g. DTS, foreign languages, commentary), or if necessary, re-encoding it at a lower quality.

Answer (score 2):

[Toast](http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/toast/titanium/overview.html) has worked well for me...

Answer (score 0):

I personally use [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html) and [LiquidCD](http://www.maconnect.ch/). Both free.

To rip DVDs you can use [MacTheRipper](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/14414) or [DVD2One](http://www.dvd2one.com/).

Answer (score -2):

DVD Remaster has worked well for me in the past [download](http://www.metakine.com/products/dvdremaster/). It also comes bundled with an application called Fairmount which will decrypt DVDs and mount them as a drive for making local copies, transcoding, or burning back to DVD.

Answer (score -2):

Use [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net) to burn your files on Mac OS X. It can also convert videos to formats, that a DVD-player can read.

Oh, and it's free... :)

Comment: I've used burn but I think it can not scale-down from 6.6 to 4.3GB
I do not know if there is any way to do this...

Comment: Toast compresses the files, but you need to pay for it.

Answer (score -2):

I do all my burning needs with [Disco](http://www.discoapp.com/). If you looking for more features, then [Toast](http://www.roxio.com/eng/products/toast/default.html) is a good alternative. It is rather expensive though.

Answer (score -2):

If you mount the image file with *Disk Utility*, you should have a *Burn* option to do that.

---

Otherwise use this command:

```
hdiutil burn image.iso
```

> Burn image to optical media in an attached burning device.

Run `man hdiutil` to see the documentation page, or `hdiutil burn -help` for list of parameters.

To list all burning devices, run: `hdiutil burn -list`.