# DVD burning software for the Mac, searching for a Nero equivalent

Tags: macos, mac, burning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mac OS DVD Burning Software](https://superuser.com/questions/18156/mac-os-dvd-burning-software)

I'd like to burn some DVDs, but the software that comes with the Mac to do this isn't up to scratch.

I haven't been able to find any so far.

Do you know of any DVD burning software for the Mac?

Comment: duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/18156/mac-os-dvd-burning-software

Comment: It's not a duplicate - I want to know how to use Disk Utility to create an ISO DVD. I don't want to know an alternative for Nero and I don't want to buy Toast (before I bought a mac folks kept telling me "It has all the software you need built in!") I want to know how to use the 'built in' facility to create a globally accepted standard DVD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html), which is free and open source, and does the few burning tasks that I need to do beyond what I can do with Finder's Burn Folders.

If you are prepared to pay money, [Disco](http://www.discoapp.com/) (19.95 USD) is pretty good. Back in the day I used [Roxio Toast](http://www.roxio.com/eng/products/toast/default.html) which is still around, but seems unnecessarily expensive compared to Burn and Disco.

Answer (score 1):

We use [LiquidCD](https://liquidcd.en.softonic.com/mac) where I work as a free alternative to Toast (which is by far the best for the Mac but costs money).

Answer (score 0):

[Toast](http://www.roxio.com/eng/products/toast/default.html) is the King, but it costs money.  I gave up with the built in Mac burning software as well.
It depends what you want to do, if its films you want to copy then use [Fairmount](http://www.metakine.com/products/fairmount/) to defeat the security and Toast to copy the VIDEO_TS folder.