# Open .cdr file on OS X

Tags: macos, iso-image

I need to open a couple of .cdr files on my Mac. I've tried changing the file extension to .iso in order to open it with the Disk Utility app, but it didn't work!

Any ideas how I can open them?

Answer (score 4):

A .cdr is a DVD/CD master likely created by Disk Utility.  You'll need to keep the extension as `.cdr`.  You can mount the file by simply double clicking on it.  You can also drag the file into disk utility and either mount or reburn from there.

Answer (score 2):

If your macOS doesn't support [disk image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_image) files with [`.cdr` extension](http://fileformat.wikia.com/wiki/CDR) such as [Roxio Toast format](https://superuser.com/a/1291787/87805); (do not confuse with [CorelDRAW format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CorelDRAW#CDR_file_format)), try renaming its file extension to `.iso`.

To check if your image file is supported by macOS, run:

```
hdiutil imageinfo file.cdr
```

Otherwise you need to either convert the file into ISO format, then use `hdiutil burn` command or some 3rd party [burning software](https://superuser.com/q/18156/87805) such as [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html) (free), [Roxio](http://www.roxio.com/enu/store/mac.html) (paid) or other.