# Which file format starts with "45 52 02" bytes?

Tags: file-format

I've got `.cdr` file format (not *CorelDRAW* file), however I've trouble opening/burning it. I expect it to be the disk image. Here are the first few lines:

```
$ hexdump -C *.cdr | head
00000000  45 52 02 00 00 70 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |ER...p..........|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000200  ...
$ hdiutil imageinfo *.cdr
hdiutil: imageinfo failed - image not recognized
```

In what kind of format is this file?

I've checked [Magic numbers in files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files) article on Wikipedia, but it's not listed there.

Comment: It very well could be a disk image: .CDR is a disc image created on a Macintosh computer using the built-in Disk Utility program; may contain multiple folders and files in a single disc image file that can be burned to a CD; similar to an .ISO file created on a Windows computer.

Comment: The `file` command is made specifically to recognize file types by looking at the magic bytes.

Comment: If it is a disk image, `.cdr` files can be renamed to `.iso` and be recognized as an ISO9660 CD-ROM image.

Comment: was 30 seconds late :) on OsX the disk image is usually named .cdr but it is in fact a standard ISO 9660. Used this fact to move data from Mac to PC

Comment: .cdr is used when one creates a CD/DVD master and uses the ISO9660 standard / .dmg is used to store/distribute OsX software/data, and can be compressed and encrypted

Comment: Not all cdrom image files will be .iso format....

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, I am not 100% on this, but it appears to be close to a [Roxio Toast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roxio_Toast) disk image file according to the [list of file signatures found here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures):

> Roxio Toast disc image file, also some .dmg-files begin with same bytes.

The hex signature provided there is:

```
45 52 02 00 00 00
```

And the hex signature you are sharing is:

```
45 52 02 00 00 70
```

Note that the last hex value is `00` instead of `70` so this is even odder. Wonder if the `70` means the image is compressed? Similar info seems to be found in [this definitions file for `pyfsig`](https://github.com/schlerp/pyfsig); a Python file signature library.

Also—if I recall correctly—the `.cdr` extension on your file would seem to indicate to me that this disk image file was made with Roxio Toast.

And FWIW, files with the `.dmg` extension—as [mentioned on the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)—are macOS [“Apple Disk Image”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Disk_Image) format images.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might be related to a slight discrepancy in the hex signature you used - i.e.: `45 52 02 00 00 00`, while the OP's signature is actually: `45 52 02 00 00 70`.

Answer (score 59):

The `file` command tells me its an "Apple Driver Map, blocksize 512":

```
printf '\x45\x52\x02\x00\x00\x70' | file -
# /dev/stdin: Apple Driver Map, blocksize 512
```

The definition is in file's sourcecode in the file [`magic/Magdir/apple`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/file/file-23/file/magic/Magdir).

Interestingly, there is a disabled entry that would match even better: "Apple Partition data".

Comment: OP should run `file` on their actual file. It might have a different answer given the whole thing.